# Issue when installing cocoapods in terminal "zsh: abort pod install"

Tags: xcode, terminal, cocoapods, podfile

- zsh shell
- m1 Macbook pro
  already installed cocoapods, then used pod init and that worked fine, opened Podfile in Xcode to edit it, and getting an error when use the pod install command.

Comment: Please paste the text of the error you're getting, and maybe the Podfile too.

Comment: Try: brew install cocoapods

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix the issue by running the following commands:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Glad it worked but don’t understand exactly why it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).